# Morph between vertex color from instancer

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, vertex-colors

I have some trouble to morph between two vertex color.
I made a morphing between two point cloud without problem, but when I try to morph vertex color, the first one is ok but second one stay black (and if change 1st and 2nd, 2nd is ok and first is black ..)

[image: morphing with GN]

[image: texture from first point cloud (second is the same]

[image: material for morph]

[image]

If someone knows about it I will be grateful !
Best regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: could you provide an example file over https://blend-exchange.com/?

Comment: In the first image you can see the GN morphing between them.
Second is my material for my point cloud (it's a ply file import and draw with instance of point)
The last one is the morphing between the two material with attribute

If I morph my first point cloud to the second, it's ok but o for the material, I can have the first material but second one is still black, I think it's maybe a problem of vertex color attribute !?

Comment: Why Attribute uses Instancer mode? I don't see any instancing in your setup

Comment: I put instancer because I draw the point cloud with instance of triangle, if I put object or geometry nothing happend !
(I edit my post with GN for the point cloud!)

Comment: For info I imported PLY files as VERTS/COLORS ONLY with this :
https://github.com/TombstoneTumbleweedArt/import-ply-as-verts